# Find truck name and sume the duration time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi everybody I'm working on a productivity analisis by truck, and I want to get the truck name and sum the duration time.  I get this error:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timedelta'
```

Here is my code

```
#Productivity analysis by truck

id = df['Vehicle ID']
vehicles = id.drop_duplicates()
vehicles = vehicles.reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)
N_Vehicles = len(vehicles)

df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'].astype(str))

for i in range(N_Vehicles):

  X[i]= df[df['Vehicle ID'] == vehicles['Vehicle ID'][i]].Duration.sum()

X
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share the exception stack trace? Which line does the error/exception occur at?

Comment: Here:  X[i]= df[df['Vehicle ID'] == vehicles['Vehicle ID'][i]].Duration.sum()

Comment: If I change this part of the comparison line (vehicles['Vehicle ID'][i]) to a truck name such as 'truck 1' and if it exists it works. but I want to make it automated

Comment: For example:  truck_1 = df[df['Vehicle ID'] == 'Truck 1'].Duration.sum()    This line works. but I want to make it automated

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if code works for `... == 'Truck 1'` but not for `... == vehicles['Vehicle ID'][i]` then first you could use `print()` and print(type(...))` to see what you really have in `vehicles['Vehicle ID'][i]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```py
for i,truck in enumerate(vehicles['Vehicle ID']):
    X[i]= df[df['Vehicle ID'] == truck].Duration.sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to initialize the vector X as follows:

```
X = [None] * N_Vehicles
```